# Is it possible to walk through the transaction chain when SGX is enabled?

Tags: corda, sgx

If I build a CorDapp in Corda open source that walks through all transaction chain to collect some data, I suppose that when SGX is enabled in Enterprise version it won't be possible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. When SGX is enabled, the transaction chain will be stored in encrypted form, readable only by the enclave. You thus won't be able to walk through and read the contents of the chain.

Comment: Can you still view transactions that you are a participants of and transactions that some broadcasted?